# PHP, using $_FILES and $_POST at the same time

Tags: php

I have a problem in using $_FILES and $_POST at the same the because I have a form to upload an image and some data bus when I use one of them it works but when I used the other one id doesn't work.
my code is :

```
    <?php
include 'debugging.php';

//phpinfo();
echo '<br />';

echo '<h1>Image Upload</h1>';

//create a form with a file upload control and a submit button
echo <<<_END
<br />
<form method='post' action='uplaodex.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='picName' size='50' />

name: <input type='text' name='usName' size='50' />
username : <input type='text' name='usUsername' size='50' />
pass: <input type='password' name='usPass' size='50' />
email: <input type='text' name='usEmail' size='50' />
<br />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1" />
</form>
<br />
_END;
//above is a special use of the echo function - everything between <<<_END 
//and _END will be treated as one large echo statement

//$_FILES is a PHP global array similar to $_POST and $_GET
if (isset($_FILES['picName'])and isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//we access the $_FILES array using the name of the upload control in the form created above    
//

    //create a file path to save the uploaded file into     
    $name = "images//" . $_FILES['picName']['name']; //unix path uses forward slash
    //'filename' index comes from input type 'file' in the form above
    //
    //move uploaded file from temp to web directory
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picName']['tmp_name'], $name)) {
       // Create the file DO and populate it.
        include 'Do_profile.php';
        $file = new Do_profile();

        //we are going to store the file type and the size so we get that info
        $type = $_FILES['picName']['type'];
        $size = $_FILES['picName']['size'];
        $usName = trim($_POST['usName']);
        $usUsername = trim($_POST['usUsername']);
        $usPass = trim($_POST['usPass']);
        $usEmail = trim($_POST['usEmail']);

        $file->FileName = $name; //$name is initialised previously using $_FILES and file path
        $file->FileSize = $size;
        $file->Type = $type;
        $file->usName = $usName;
        $file->usUsername = $usUsername;
        $file->usPass = $usPass;
        $file->usEmail = $usEmail;

        if ($file->save()) {
//select the ID of the image just stored so we can create a link                

//display success message                      
                echo "<h1> Thankyou </h1><p>Image stored successfully</p>";
//this above line of code displays the image now stored in the images sub directory                      
                echo "<p>Uploaded image '$name'</p><br /><img src='$name' height='200' width='200'/>";
//create alink to the page we will use to display the stored image                      
                echo '<br><a href="Display.php?id=' . $fileId . '">Display image ' .
                $file->FileName . '</a>';
            } else
                echo '<p class="error">Error retrieving file information</p>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was a databse error</p>';
        }
    } else {
        //error handling in case move_uploaded_file() the file fails
        $error_array = error_get_last();
        echo "<p class='error'>Could not move the file</p>";

      //  foreach($error_array as $err)
        //    echo $err;
    }


echo "</body></html>";


?>
```

I don't know what is the problem, any help??

Comment: can you define *"doesn't work"* ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the whole code from if (isset($_FILES['picName'])and isset($_POST['submit']) skipped and the all lines are useless

Answer (score 4):

Everything inside that `if (isset($_FILES['picName'])and isset($_POST['submit']))` doesn't work because the superglobal `$_FILES` is probably not having a key named `picName`. To check this out, try `var_dump`-ing the `$_FILES`, like `var_dump($_FILES);`

By the output of the `var_dump` you'd get to know if there is any content inside `$_FILES`. And if it is populated, just see what the key name is and, access the file by using that key.

But if the array is empty, there may be some mis-configurations in PHP, or APACHE.

One possible fix would be setting `file_uploads = On` in the ini file for php.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found the problem that you can't use $_FILES and $_POST at the same time

Comment: I spliced the code into tow IF (issues...) but now only if that has the save method works , I'm trying to pass the $_Post values into $_FILES to perform the save method

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to validate the size of the file if you want to do an isset. I don't know if this is works, but the better way for do that is check first the size for validate if isset or was send to the server.
2. Then, in your `<form method='post' action='uplaodex.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>` you have to create another PHP file with the name uplaodex.php where you'll send al the data. So, your code with be like the below code following and considering the step 1. This will be your uploadex.php

   ```
   $name_file       = $_FILES['picName']['name'];
   $type            = $name_file['type'];
   $size            = $name_file['size'];
   $tmp_folder      = $name_file['tmp'];
   $usName          = trim($_POST['usName']);
   $usUsername      = trim($_POST['usUsername']);
   $usPass          = trim($_POST['usPass']);
   $usEmail         = trim($_POST['usEmail']);

   if ( $size > 0 ) {
       //REMOVE another slash images//
       $name = "images/" . $name_file; //unix path uses forward slash
       //'filename' index comes from input type 'file' in the form above
       //
       //move uploaded file from temp to web directory
       if ( move_uploaded_file($tmp_folder, $name) ) {
          // Create the file DO and populate it.
           include 'Do_profile.php';
           $file             = new Do_profile();
           $file->FileName   = $name; //$name is initialised previously using $_FILES and file path
           $file->FileSize   = $size;
           $file->Type       = $type;
           $file->usName     = $usName;
           $file->usUsername = $usUsername;
           $file->usPass     = $usPass;
           $file->usEmail    = $usEmail;
               if ($file->save()) {   
                       //USE PRINTF
                       printf('<h1> Thankyou </h1><p>Image stored successfully</p><br> 
                               <p>Uploaded file: %s</p>. <img src="%s" height="200" width="200" />',
                               $name_file, $name );

                       #WHAT IS $fileId? In which moment was define?
                       //echo '<br><a href="Display.php?id=' . $fileId . '">Display image ' .
                       $file->FileName . '</a>';
               } 

               else
                   echo '<p class="error">Error retrieving file information</p>';
               }

       else {
           echo '<p class="error"> Oh dear. There was a databse error</p>';
       } //ENDIF OF if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picName']['tmp_name'], $name))

   } //ENDIF OF  if ( $size > 0 )

   #ELSE OF YOUR if ( $size > 0 )
   else {
       //error handling in case move_uploaded_file() the file fails
       $error_array = error_get_last();
       echo "<p class='error'>Could not move the file</p>";

     //  foreach($error_array as $err)
       //    echo $err;
   }
   ```

Comment: the problem that two methods don't work at the same time, kindly see the comment in the upper post and see if you could help. many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, you can't perform $_FILES and $_post at the same time or one of them inside the other.
start with $_Post and then $_FILES and outside the $_FILES run your saving function

thats it

Comment: This answer is just completely incorrect, not an answer, and reflects a lack of understanding of what php arrays are.